# Force Netbeans a coding review a specific language

Tags: javascript, php, netbeans

Wonder if is possible in netbeans to force a coding review, for example a .php file that only contains javascript code written.
It works as expected if i add the script tag but i dont want this. How can i force netbeans to code review it without the tag.

Comment: I can't think of any way to do this without changing PHP files to use the JS interpreter

Comment: Its a bit problematic while you troubleshooting code, i wish that netbeans suported this.